# Will BlackBerry application for OS 7.1 work for BlackBerry OS 10?

Tags: blackberry

Please tell me will BlackBerry application till OS 7.1 work for new BlackBerry OS version 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At BlackBerry10Jam London yesterday, it was said on stage that in future RIM aim to offer support for apps that ran on previous versions of BB OS. By that I guess they mean they are looking to adapt the Android App support they have for BB 10 (which is in effect a java/dalvik runtime within which you can run some Android apps). No time frames though.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work if it's written in java. If you used webworks,html5 etc, it will work on os 10

Comment: it means, each application which is made for older versions(in java) need to developed again for new os 10?

Comment: After the Blackberry PlayBook tablet was first released, which uses the same OS that BB10 is based on, there was talk of an App Player being added for running BB Java apps, just like there is an App Player in 2.x for running Android apps. The BB App Player was never released, though.